# Test if Warning was issued

Tags: python, testing, warnings, pytest

I am creating a class and assigning one of it's attributes to a variable

```
val = ClassName(*args).val
```

While creating this class a function is called which issues a `Warning`. I have verified this by using print statements before and after. How do I check for the warning using py.test? I have tried the following after looking at the [documentation](https://pytest.org/latest/recwarn.html):

```
def test_warning(self, recwarn):
     val = ClassName(*args).val
    `assert recwarn.pop(RuntimeWarning)`
```

This tells me that `RuntimeWarning` was never issued.

```
AssertionError: <type 'exceptions.RuntimeWarning'> not found in warning list
```

What am I missing?